# How best to keep a map of one managed object to another that keeps in sync in Swift?

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, notifications, maps

Here's my situation: I have a notification that's sent out that corresponds to a certain "alarm" in my application (the Object is called Alarm). AlarmMO objects are a subclass of NSManagedObject, for use in Core Data. When I send a notification to the user, I want them to be able to snooze the alarm, which in essence calls a function on an Alarm object to do its magic. The way I've thought to do this is in my main view controller, implement this function:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter, didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse, withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void)
```

I've already set my UITableViewController to adopt the UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate protocol. This function will get called when the action is pressed on the notification. When this function gets called, I will be able to get the alarmNotificationIdentifier using

```
let alarmNotificationIdentifier = response.notification.request.identifier
```

This alarmNotificationIdentifier is a UUID that I've tied a certain AlarmMO object (which one I will have to find out at runtime by just searching each AlarmMO object for this UUID in its notificationUuids array). Once I have the AlarmMO object that corresponds to the notification, I need to get the actual Alarm object that corresponds to the AlarmMO object. How is the best way to do this? How can I make sure to keep the arrays of these two objects synced (I have two arrays at the top of my ViewController, [AlarmMO] and [Alarm])?

Comment: Why do you have separate `Alarm` and `AlarmMO` objects?  You should have one object.

Comment: @Paulw11 How would this look? Would I make all of my properties in Alarm.swift have `@NSManaged` before them or would I create all new versions of these variables that deal with Core Data and keep the other variables separate?

Comment: It is hard to say without seeing the objects. Typically I use an extension to the generated managed object subclass to add computed variables and functions as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet to ask for more detail, so I will try to answer as best as possible first:

Do you need those two arrays of AlarmMO and Alarm? I mean, are there many many objects in them and you make crucial computations for each one?

If not, why not go with a Dictionary of the type `[AlarmMO : Alarm]`?
You can still get all the AlarmMO objects and Alarm objects when necessary by calling `youDictionaryVariable.keys` -> [AlarmMO] and `youDictionaryVariable.values` -> [Alarm] .

Now if you want the corresponding `Alarm` object, make use of the dictionary: `let correspondingAlarmObject = dictionary[AlarmMO]`